# KeyGenerator initialise crashes on API 23

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, encryption, keystore

I'm trying to make an encryption/decryption class using Keystore but it crashes on API 23. I knew that this is the Api that should start supporting it.

Exception Thrown:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Not Implemented
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseKeyGenerator.engineInit(BaseKeyGenerator.java:40)
```

This is how I generate my key.

```
 private fun generateSecretKey(): SecretKey {
        return KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM).apply {
            init(
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                    .setKeySize(256) // key size in bits
                    .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                    .build()
            )
        }.generateKey()
    }


companion object {
        private const val ALIAS = "secret_key"
        private const val ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES
        private const val BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC
        private const val PADDING = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        private const val TRANSFORMATION = "$ALGORITHM/$BLOCK_MODE/$PADDING"
    }
```

Anyone here encountered this and can tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the provider in the `getInstance` call.
Try this

```
private fun generateSecretKey(): SecretKey {
        return KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, "AndroidKeyStore").apply {
            init(
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                    .setKeySize(256) // key size in bits
                    .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                    .build()
            )
        }.generateKey()
    }
```